# Group by and join with Hibernate and JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

I have some models with dependencies between them. Here are the models:

```
@Entity
public class A extends Model {
    @Required
    public String name;

    @Required
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public C modelC;
}

@Entity
public class B extends Model {
    @Required
    public String name;
}

@Entity
public class C extends Model {
    @Required
    public Date lastUpdate;

    @Required
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "modelC", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<A> modelsA;

    @Required
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public B modelB;
}
```

As you can see the model named `C` contains several models named `A` and one model named `B`.

What I would like to do is to select all models `C` that have a distinct model `B` (distinct by their `id`) and that have the greatest `date` (closer to the current date). Also, I would like to select the dependencies of the model `C` (list of `A` and the model `B`).

I have the query to load all models `C` and its dependencies:

```
select distinct c from C c
left join fetch c.modelsA
left join fecth c.modelB
```

I think I can retrieve only the distinct models `C` (distinct by the id of the model `B`) and its dependencies with this query:

```
select distinct c from C c
left join fetch c.modelsA
left join fetch c.modelB b
group by b.id
```

However, how can I retrieve the distinct models `C` with the highest date? This does not work:

```
select distinct c, max(c.lastUpdate) as maxUpdate from C c
left join fetch c.modelsA
left join fetch c.modelB b
group by b.id
```

Can you help me?

Here is an example of data:

```
B(b1):
  name: First model of type B

B(b2):
  name: Second model of type B

C(c1):
  lastUpdate: 100
  modelB: b1

C(c2):
  lastUpdate: 200
  modelB: b2

C(c3):
  lastUpdate: 300
  modelB: b1

A(a1):
  name: A1
  modelC: c1

A(a2):
  name: A2
  modelC: c1

A(a3):
  name: A3
  modelC: c2

A(a4):
  name: A4
  modelC: c3
```

I would like to retrieve this `c2` and `c3` and their dependencies.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can use order By,moreover with the hql your not obliged to do a left join, join is valide too, becareful for the fetch utilisation.

max(modelC.lastUpdate) maybe try this or c.modelC.lastUpdate

example

```
 query = "select u from User u "
+ "left join u.linkedAccounts linkedAccounts "
+ "where u.active =  true "
    + "and **linkedAccounts.providerKey** = :pProviderKey" ),
```